# How do I make remote debug JVM not output text on stdout, stderr?

Tags: java, language-server-protocol

I'm currently writing a language server (atop of lsp4j), and need to debug my language server. Language server protocol servers uses stdin and stdout to communicate with the client.

Now I want to debug a server that is launched from the client (VSCode), so I added in the debug flags for the spawned JVM process:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

Upon doing this suddenly, the server does not work any more, even though suspend = 0 and I confirmed the port is open and that no firewall malarkey is happening.

I decided to run the command line manually, and I see that the first thing that a process does, after it receives the debug parameters is to output the following to stdout:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
```

(emitted without double quotes)

I believe this is the reason that I cannot debug the language server, because outputting anything to stdout or stdin that is not part of the language server protocol [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol/blob/master/versions/protocol-2-x.md) forces the client to reject the server.

My question therefore, in a roundabout fashion is to ask if it is possible to make internal JVM messages on stdout, stdin, stderr silent via another JVM parameter?

Answer (score 6):

Update:

The answer appears to be ",quiet=y" as an additional parameter.

> -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999,quiet=y

Thank you to Christian Dietrich for providing the solution on the lsp4j github page.